# Android image with rounded corners

Tags: java, optimization, android

I've followed [this blog](http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners) to get images with nice pretty rounded corners in Android.

I've managed to strip out a lot of the superfluous `arrayAdapter` stuff and make it much more simple.

I've largely tweaked this just until I made it work.  Does anyone have any feedback?

```
class StreamDrawable extends Drawable {

    private final float mCornerRadius;
    private final RectF mRect = new RectF();
    private final BitmapShader mBitmapShader;
    private final Paint mPaint;
    private final int mMargin;

    StreamDrawable(Bitmap bitmap, float cornerRadius, int margin) {
        mCornerRadius = cornerRadius;

        mBitmapShader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setShader(mBitmapShader);

        mMargin = margin;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
        super.onBoundsChange(bounds);
        mRect.set(mMargin, mMargin, bounds.width() - mMargin, bounds.height() - mMargin);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(mRect, mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        mPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        mPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
    }       
}



public void drawit(){
    final int CORNER_RADIUS = 24; // dips
    final int MARGIN = 12; // dips

    final int mCornerRadius;
    final int mMargin;

    final float density = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    mCornerRadius = (int) (CORNER_RADIUS * density + 0.5f);
    mMargin = (int) (MARGIN * density + 0.5f);

    ImageView imgvw = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.london);

    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, imgvw.getWidth(), imgvw.getHeight(), false);


    StreamDrawable d = new StreamDrawable(resizedBitmap, mCornerRadius, mMargin);
    imgvw.setBackground(d);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks very clean to me. Except perhaps:

- `imgvw` - that's **disemvoweling**. nd t's bd. Not to mention it's breaking your *camelCasing* convention for locals.
- `drawit` - while the name says what the function does, I would avoid *DoThatThing* names and perhaps go for a more sober `render` method name, if not just `draw`.

Lastly, I don't know Java well enough to know if it's convention, but I wouldn't use that `m` prefix.

Comment: The `m` prefix **is** a convention in Java :) (sometimes used, sometimes not. But there's nothing wrong with using it)